# getElementsByClassName plus a value filter of the data inside this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains, getelementsbyclassname

I need to add a filter to a function.

I have different elements in the page with the class `a-text-center table-border`, but I need the code working only if the element value is > 1, so other elements won't be affected by the script.

I can not add anything to the code, such as an ID or anything else to the element to differentiate it from the others, so the only way to differentiate it is using the `value` of the number inside this element.

Example of the element:

```
<td class="a-text-center table-border">4</td>
```

In this case the value is `4`.

This is the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = (document).getElementsByClassName('a-text-center table-border');
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    x.item(i).className += " bordertopred";
```

Comment: Why is `document` in brackets?

Comment: Why is an `if` statement not working here?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that `td` elements do not have a `value`. What you're trying to read is the `innerText` of the element. This can be done using `filter()` after selecting the necessary elements from the DOM.

Also note that if you include jQuery in the page you may as well make use of it to do what you require. Below are two versions of the code, one utilising jQuery and the other plain JS.

First the plain JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let valueToMatch = '4';
  let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.a-text-center.table-border')).filter(el => el.innerText.trim() === valueToMatch);
  elements.forEach(el => el.classList.add("bordertopred"));
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px; 
}
.bordertopred {
  background-color: #CC0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">1</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">2</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">3</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This would be the jQuery equivalent:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let valueToMatch = '4';
  $('.a-text-center.table-border').filter((i, el) => el.innerText.trim() === valueToMatch).addClass('bordertopred');
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px; 
}
.bordertopred {
  background-color: #CC0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">1</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">2</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">3</td>
    <td class="a-text-center table-border">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "*The collection returned from getElementsByClassName() doesn't have an items() method.*" no, it's not plural but [`HTMLCollection#item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item) does exist.

Comment: @VLAZ very good point  - I'll update the answer

Comment: "*it should be item().*" that's what OP already uses...

Comment: "*getElementsByClassName() accepts a single class only*" - [it does work with multiple ones](https://jsbin.com/muzabazabe/1/edit?html,js,console). I still would suggest a `querySelectorAll` here as it's clearer but the current code is not wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm pretty sure the question got ninja edited while I was answering, as the OP added the note about the 'value' actually being the text of a `td` cell. I've edited the question again to give a clearer explanation of the original issues

Comment: Yep, I don't remember the TD thing being there. Because I remember thinking that OP either doesn't know how to call `.value` or how to get the content of an element and that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I not understand.
You can't add `if` statement at your function?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = (document).getElementsByClassName('a-text-center table-border');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   if (i > 1)
     x.item(i).className += " bordertopred";
}
</script>
```

Also i would be inclined to use `x.item(i).className.add('yourclass');`

Comment: If I'm not wrong this will only skip the first element inside the array. Your if statement should check about the value attribute of each element instead of the index.

Comment: I really like the "if" option, however, it is not working, the code is still adding the class to any td matching the className, it is not limiting to only the innerText specified.  What about if we limit the work to only the innerText = 4 ?